# DataGridView ICustomTypeDescriptor

Tags: dynamic, datagridview, properties, icustomtypedescriptor

I´m want build a DataGridView with Databinding to a Class where I can add Properties at Runtime. 
I want to add Columns at runtime and have the values stored in the class. 
I found a nice example [here](http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/01/implementing-icustomtypedescriptor-for.html) (Dictionary to store Properties with ICustomTypeDescriptor)

It works fine til i want read information from the DataGridView. I get NullReferenzException or IndexOutOfBoundException.

I think something is missing in my BindingClass with the ICustomTypeDescriptor. 
The .NET designer don´t create Columns in Visual Studio but therea are created at programmstart.

I will be realy glad, if someone could help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I suggest checking the column management.
Maybe you have forgotten for example assigning the Name or DataPropertyName properties of the column...

Please give more description of your problem + some code.

Comment: The code is quite the same as in the hyperlink. (its way to much to show here)

It seems the binding is not complete.
The Columns with Cells are not really in the Gridview. I can seeh them but i cannot use them.